# Change ng-bootstrap buttons activeClass?

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

In out AngularJs app, we changed the `activeClass` of buttons (as in toggle groups) to `btn-default` (from the default `btn-primary`), so all our CSS expects that.

I notice that ng-bootstrap also defaults to `btn-primary` but I don't see how (or *if*) that can be changed.

Is it possible for me to change the activeClass so my CSS is correct with the new components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-bootstrap make use of bootstrap 4. Bootstrap 4 includes [six predefined button styles](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#examples), each serving its own semantic purpose. But it doesn't include a `btn-default` but with `btn-secondary` class you achieve the same styling.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" [class.active]="model.left">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.left"> Left (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" [class.active]="model.middle">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.middle"> Middle
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" [class.active]="model.right">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.right"> Right
  </label>
</div>
```

If you still prefer to use the `btn-default` then you can make a class with that name in your component style and use it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, which version of angular are you using?
there's quite difference between ng versions

**ng-1** [angularjs.org - docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<button ng-class="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">
    it's a button
</button>
```

**ng-2/4** [angular.io - docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)

```
<button [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">
    it's a button
</button>
```

Comment: I'm using Angular 4

Comment: so the second should work, if you expose a boolean variable :)